# Calculation of a position from the angles of arrival

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals, signal-detection, array-signal-processing

For locating a target by TDOA (Time Difference Of Arrival) with $3$ stations we have the Chan method which gives an exact solution of the position.

I keep the $3$ stations but instead of measuring the arrival times, I look for the arrival angles noted by $ \theta_i$, $i \in [1,3]$. Similar to TDOA, I look at the difference between the angles of arrival, i.e. $\theta_i - \theta_1$ for example.

Here are my questions: 1) Is this difference between angle of arrival interesting in this case?
2) In TDOA base stations do not need to be synchronized but what about for AOA?